# How to get all system/bios information for Windows

Tags: winapi, go, wmi, bios

I want to know how to get full information about **PC and BIOS**. I came across this post - *https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/golang-nuts/pKuFQxAy4P4/62FnqGON1pEJ*

**Code:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ochapman/godmi"
)
func main(){
    BS:=godmi.GetBIOSInformation()
    fmt.Println("BS:",BS)
    sys:=godmi.GetSystemInformation()
    fmt.Println("sys:",sys)
    BB:=godmi.GetBaseboardInformation()
    fmt.Println("BB:",BB)
}
```

**I could not compile because there is an error:**

```
# github.com/ochapman/godmi
go\src\github.com\ochapman\godmi\godmi.go:674:13: undefined: syscall.Mmap
go\src\github.com\ochapman\godmi\godmi.go:674:79: undefined: syscall.PROT_RE
go\src\github.com\ochapman\godmi\godmi.go:674:98: undefined: syscall.MAP_SHA
go\src\github.com\ochapman\godmi\godmi.go:680:8: undefined: syscall.Munmap
```

As I understood it only for **Linux**, for **Windows** I did not find anything like it at all. **Can eat an alternative?**

Comment: Please post your own code (or what you've tried), the desired behavior, and the actual behavior. For some basic guidelines see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @ChaimEliyah updated the question

Answer (score 3):

#### A detour about the methodology in programming

(Sorry for a detour, which follows, but I think I had to make it.)

You're attacking your problem from a wrong angle.
Programming is not about finding a random package, trying it,
seeing it failing and turning for help;
it's rather about inventing a general approach to solving the problem
at hand and then trying to figure out what are there to solve it.

For instance, in your case, it might easily be not fruitful
to search for "BIOS+information+golang" because *it's too narrow.*

Instead, try to figure out

1. How to get *any* information *about a system* on Windows.
2. How to do that in Go.

While this is boring, I have to recommend reading
[this](http://whathaveyoutried.com) seriously: this will really help
you getting your future programming challenges solved.

#### The problem at hand

OK, now back to your problem.

On Windows, the standard way to obtain information about a system
is querying the so-called [Windows Management Instrumentation
(or WMI for short)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Management_Instrumentation)  subsystem.

Once you know this, you should dig into these two directions:

- What WMI calls do you need to perform to get the information
  which is of interest to you.

  This one is easily searcheable.
  The first hit I got doing that is [this](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/02/17/useful-wmic-queries/)
  which I'd say is a pretty good start.
- How to do WMI calls from Go.

  This one can be done in two ways:

  - Direct implementation by hand.
    Go has very good built-in support for dynamically loading Windows DLLs
    and calling functions from them.

    [This](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc/blob/master/api/zapi_windows.go) is a good demonstation of the basic concepts.
  - Using a ready-made package.
    Again, quick searching yields [`github.com/StackExchange/wmi`](https://godoc.org/github.com/StackExchange/wmi).

So, if I were you, I'd first code up whatever the WMI calls suit my needs
using VBS or JScript (or whatnot) on [WSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)
and then "ported" that solution to Go using any of the described approaches.

Comment: That detour is brilliant!

Comment: Спасибо вам большое. Но я одного не могу понять и не могу найти: Как мне сменить запрос допустим на bios, пробовал Win32_Bios но пишет Invalid Class или Invalid Query. Информацию как сменить запрос не нашел.

Comment: @JackSmith, sorry I don't even have access to Windows and was writing off my memory. [This](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c5684592-adaf-4fcd-8adb-335c7633ca71/query-bios-version-before-running-command-or-installing-application?forum=mdt) has a working WMI query for bios: `select * from WIN32_BIOS where SMBIOSBIOSVersion < "A26"` so I'd work from there. See also [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa394077.aspx).

Comment: @JackSmith …and [this](https://www.google.ru/search?q=WMI+BIOS+site%3Arsdn.ru) and the links provided [here](https://habrahabr.ru/post/138400/#comment_4622655) and so on. Please do your research.

Comment: @kostix this is most importand for me i was able to find it - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396